# Rails precompile assests fail with return outside of function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, asset-pipeline

```
    [176.71.146.44] executing command
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Execute assets:precompile
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Execute assets:precompile:all
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Execute assets:environment
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Invoke environment (first_time)
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Execute environment
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Execute tmp:cache:clear
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] ** Execute assets:precompile:primary
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 
 ** [out :: 176.71.146.44] 'return' outside of function (line: 29773, col: 8, pos: 908864)
```

Anyone know this error?

Comment: What command do you run exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen that error, but most of my `asset:precompile` errors end up being problems within a particular asset.

When I have an unexplained error, I start trying one thing at a time. If you are using source control, can you roll back to a previous change that works? If it's not checked in yet, use Git stash, Perforce shelf, or similar.

Here's someone that had a similar compilation error from a CoffeeScript file: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-12178

Hope that helps.